# Attempting to handle tap event from UIButton in UITableView cell causes invalid selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am attempting to handle the tap event of a UIButton in a UITableView cell but unfortunately the app crashes with the error message:

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f95984cbaf0
```

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // this is a simplified version of this method for brevity.
    NSMutableArray* views = [NSMutableArray array];

    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithThinBorderedColor_QAN:[UIColor colorForPrimaryUse]
                                                highlightedColor:nil
                                                   disabledColor:nil];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [views addObject:button];
    [cell setContents:views withConfiguration:configuration];
    return cell;
}
```

In myViewController.h (simplified version) I have:

```
@interface SEFSFormEditingViewController : UITableViewController

- (void) showSomething;

@end
```

In myViewController.m I have:

```
-(void)showSomething:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
    NSString* test= @"test";
    }
}
```

When I run the app the button is correctly displayed but when I tap it the app crashes.

Could someone please point me to the right direction on to fix this problem?

Comment: You have a parameter in action. Write it: @selector(showSomething:)

Comment: try my code its 100 % work correctly.

Comment: just add UIButton *yourbutton = sender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your following line of code

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

With

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in here

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSomething) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Change to

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)aMethod:(UIButton*)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.TABLENAME];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.TABLENAME indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

}
```